# SIGNAL: QStandarditemmodel::datachanged(...) does not emit roles when using QStandarditemmodel::setData(...))

Tags: c++, qt, qt-signals, slot

my Problem is, when using

```cpp
QStandarditemmodel::setData(const QModelIndex &index, const QVariant &value, int role)
```

it seems that the role is never emitted.

Example:

```cpp
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
QMainWindow(parent),
ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{

QStandardItemModel *model = new QStandardItemModel();

QList<QStandardItem*> itemList;
itemList.append(new QStandardItem());

model->appendRow(itemList);

connect(model, SIGNAL(dataChanged(QModelIndex,QModelIndex,QVector<int>)), this, SLOT(myslot_dataChanged(QModelIndex,QModelIndex,QVector<int>)));

model->item(0,0)->setData("supercool value", Qt::DisplayRole); // // should emit 1 role, but 0 are arriving
model->item(0,0)->setData("another supercool value", Qt::UserRole); //  // should emit 1 role, but 0 are arriving

QVector<int> roles;
roles.append(Qt::DisplayRole); 
roles.append(Qt::UserRole);
emit model->dataChanged(model->index(0,0), model->index(0,0), roles); // works. roles.count() == 2
}

MainWindow::myslot_dataChanged(const QModelIndex &topLeft, const QModelIndex &bottomRight, const QVector<int> &roles)
{
    qDebug() << roles.count();
}
```

given Output:

```
0
0
2
```

expected Output:

```
1
1
2
```

I know that the roles QVector in the signal is optional. Could it somehow be possible that Qt omit the roles und just uses the default ones? Maybe I have  to use the right signal (NOT the ones where you can omit the roles...) explicitely, but i dont know how.

Sorry for bad english, and thank you for help! ;)

Edit 1: Further Investigations:

I've crawled through the Qt sources and found this in qstandarditemmodel.cpp

```cpp
void QStandardItem::setData(const QVariant &value, int role)
{
    Q_D(QStandardItem);
    role = (role == Qt::EditRole) ? Qt::DisplayRole : role;
    QVector<QStandardItemData>::iterator it;
    for (it = d->values.begin(); it != d->values.end(); ++it) {
        if ((*it).role == role) {
            if (value.isValid()) {
                if ((*it).value.type() == value.type() && (*it).value == value)
                    return;
                (*it).value = value;
            } else {
                d->values.erase(it);
            }
            if (d->model)
                d->model->d_func()->itemChanged(this);
            return;
        }
    }
    d->values.append(QStandardItemData(role, value));
    if (d->model)
        d->model->d_func()->itemChanged(this);
}
```

When using setData the function itemChanged is used which does not care about the roles. It seems that the roles parameter in dataChanged is just optional for you and never used by native Qt functions.

Edit 2: even more investigations...

I stepped through the setData function.
Here is the snippet when setData calls itemChanged():

```cpp
void QStandardItemModelPrivate::itemChanged(QStandardItem *item)
{
    Q_Q(QStandardItemModel);
    Q_ASSERT(item);
    if (item->d_func()->parent == 0) {
        // Header item
        int idx = columnHeaderItems.indexOf(item);
        if (idx != -1) {
            emit q->headerDataChanged(Qt::Horizontal, idx, idx);
        } else {
            idx = rowHeaderItems.indexOf(item);
            if (idx != -1)
                emit q->headerDataChanged(Qt::Vertical, idx, idx);
        }
    } else {
        // Normal item
        QModelIndex index = q->indexFromItem(item);
        emit q->dataChanged(index, index);
    }
}
```

As mentioned in the previous investigations setData calls `itemChanged` which in turn calls `emit q->dataChanged(index, index);`
There we see dataChanged omits the role parameter. This means my previous guess, that Qt native functions dont use the roles, seems to be confirmed.

Comment: First of all, assert your connections: `bool ok = connect(model, ...); Q_ASSERT(ok);` - or at least look for Qt error messages in the output window.

Comment: If you have a debug build of Qt, you can step through the signal-slot-connection. It's all in the same thread in your example, so it's all simple function calls.

Comment: For what it's worth, a quick glance through the `Qt` source suggests that the role parameter to `dataChanged` *is* omitted -- as you suspected.  Was just a quick check though.

Comment: @MartinHennings: `ok == true`. No error messages. stepping through the connecting process seems to exceed my skills. Iam not smarter after doing so, but nevertheless thanks for the hint.

Comment: I'm sorry, I wasn't precise enough. You don't need to step into the `connect(...)`, because basically that's only an insert into a list of receivers. You can debug the signal-slot-invocation `emit dataChanged()`. The relevant question is: Does the call `model->item(0,0)->setData(...)` invoke an internal `emit dataChanged()` and if not, why not? If you need help, we could continue that in chat.

Comment: @MartinHennings I've done so. Thanks. See the results above. PS: dont be confused by "BenniH". Its my account, I just took the wrong login accidently .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the docs of the signal [`QAbstractItemModel::dataChanged()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#dataChanged) (emphasis by me):

> **`void QAbstractItemModel::dataChanged(const QModelIndex &topLeft, const QModelIndex &bottomRight, const QVector<int> &roles = ...)`**
>   [...]
>   The optional *roles* argument can be used to specify which data roles have actually been modified. An **empty vector** in the *roles* argument means that **all roles** should be considered modified.

As you stated, Qt's implementation of `QStandardItemModel` doesn't care to specify for which roles data changed, but instead specifies that **all** data should be updated.

The answer to the question (you didn't ask) is:

If your slot is called with a specific set of `roles`, you can optimize for that. If `roles` is empty, you need to fetch data for *all* roles that are relevant to your view.

Comment: I read the docs aswell. For me it was not obvious enough, that dataChanged(...)  indeed uses an empty role vector. Your answer sums up our previous guess very well so I mark it as solved. Thanks!